Dropdown not visible in jetpack compose android?
DropDownMenu has a parent box and an anchor button but still its not visible? I have enabled it to true, is there something i am missing to show a dropdown menu in jetpack compose?
Code is Described below with image attached
@Composable
fun DropdownButton(buttonText: String, menuList: List<String>) {
    Box(
        

    ) {

        Button(onClick = {}) {
            Text(buttonText)
        }
        DropdownMenu(expanded = true, onDismissRequest = {}, modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            menuList.forEach {
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text(text = it)
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
@Composable
fun UnitConvert(name: String = "Akshay", modifier: Modifier? = null) {

    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Column(
            Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            Text(text = "Unit Convertor", color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary)
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = {},
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter value") })
            ButtonGroup({DropdownButton(
                buttonText = "Input Unit",
                menuList = listOf("Ton", "Kilogram", "Gram", "Milligram")
            )})

        }

    }


}






I think this happens because the DropdownMenu was set to Modifier#fillMaxSize. also, for the dynamic opening and closing of the menu, we should create a state isExpanded.
because, converting that to a mutable state & wrapping that in a remember block makes the UI to recompose everytime the value of the variable isExpanded changes.
I have modified the code to a working state below, please check.
@Composable
fun DropdownButton(buttonText: String, menuList: List<String>) {
    var isExpanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Box {
        Button(onClick = {
            isExpanded = !isExpanded
        }) {
            Text(buttonText)
        }
        DropdownMenu(
            expanded = isExpanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                isExpanded = false
            }
        ) {
            menuList.forEach {
                DropdownMenuItem(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Text(text = it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun UnitConvert(name: String = "Akshay", modifier: Modifier? = null) {
    Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
        Column(
            Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {

            Text(text = "Unit Convertor", color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = "",
                onValueChange = {},
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Enter value") })
            ButtonGroup {
                DropdownButton(
                    buttonText = "Input Unit",
                    menuList = listOf("Ton", "Kilogram", "Gram", "Milligram")
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


I edited your code to switch back to the Material 2 DropdownMenuItem that was used in the question from the Material 3 version you used in your answer. Also I added the ButtonGroup back again that you removed for no apparent reason. If you want to provide full code as an answer, please make sure it actually works the way the asker expects it to work. Otherwise the answer is fine and should solve the problem, +1.
